# rails 3.1 - auto compile SASS before browser refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I used to run `compass -watch` to ensure my Sass files compiled as soon as they were modified.  Now though, thanks to the asset pipeline, code auto-compiles (if changes are detected) when the view is refreshed in the browser. There's a time-cost associated with this, especially if you frequently modify your Sass files. I'm spending half my development time waiting on views to refresh.

I'm wondering if there's a way to compile sass **before** a page refresh in rails 3.1. I tried the sass-guard gem but it doesn't seem to do what I want in rails 3.1. Perhaps there's another way?

Comment: if this can help - https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost

Comment: @rtdp thanks, I just installed that gem and my development server is definitely way faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this using [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) - now my code changes take effect before I've even switched from text-editor to browser, which cuts down on RSI-inducing mouse movements considerably